# Risk-Parity Portfolio Optimization using Extreme Optimization in C#

Tags: programming, portfolio-management, portfolio-selection

I'm trying to create a risk-parity portfolio in C# using the Extreme Optimization routines.

I'm mostly trying them out to see if I like them or not before I buy them (I'm a student so money is tight).

My idea was to implement this new kind of portfolio optimization called risk-parity. It basically says that in order to diversify your portfolio you should give equal risk to each of its components.

I'm getting a null error when running `np1.Solve()` and I don't understand why. I thought that everything else was calculated by Extreme Optimization.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there a faster way to do this optimization that I'm not aware of?
3. If you don't know the EO Libraries, but could implement this with something else, could you please drop a comment on how you would go about solving this?

By the way, the details on the portfolio construction are in the comments of the distance function, in case you're interested.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Extreme.Statistics;
using Extreme.Mathematics;
using Extreme.Mathematics.Optimization;

namespace TestingRiskParityOptimization
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            NonlinearProgram np1 = new NonlinearProgram(2);
            Func<Vector, double> distance = DistanceFunction;
            np1.ObjectiveFunction = distance;
            np1.InitialGuess = Vector.CreateConstant(2, 1.0 / ((double)2));

            np1.AddNonlinearConstraint(x => x[0] + x[1], ConstraintType.GreaterThanOrEqual, 0);
            Vector solution = np1.Solve();

            Console.WriteLine("Solution: {0:F6}", solution);
            Console.WriteLine("Optimal value:   {0:F6}", np1.OptimalValue);
            Console.WriteLine("# iterations: {0}", np1.SolutionReport.IterationsNeeded);

            Console.Write("Press Enter key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private static double DistanceFunction(Vector Weights)
        {
            Matrix Sigma = Matrix.Create(new double[,] {
                  {0.1, 0.2},
                  {0.2, 0.4}
                });
            // if VarP = Weights' * CovarMatrix * Weights and VolP = sqrt(VarP)
            // Then the marginal contribution to risk of an asset is the i-th number of
            // Sigma*Weights*VolP
            // And thus the contribution to risk of an asset is simply Weights . (Sigma*Weights/VarP)
            // we need to find weights such that Weights (i) * Row(i) of (Sigma*Weights/VarP) = 1/N

            // that is we want to minimize the distance of row vector (Weights (i) * Row(i) of (Sigma*Weights/VarP)) and vector 1/N

            double Variance = Vector.DotProduct(Weights, Sigma * Weights);

            Vector Beta = Sigma * Weights / Variance;

            for (int i = 0; i < Beta.Length; i++)
            {
                // multiplies row of beta by weight to find the percent contribution to risk
                Beta[i] = Weights[i] * Beta[i];
            }

            Vector ObjectiveVector = Vector.CreateConstant(Weights.Length, 1.0 / ((double)Weights.Length));
            Vector Distance = Vector.Subtract(Beta, ObjectiveVector);

            return Math.Sqrt(Vector.DotProduct(Distance, Distance));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure of your constraint? aren't you willing to do $x_1+x_2=1$?

Comment: It isn't necessary since I can give them the right weights after the optimization (the distance from the optimal risk-parity weights won't change after a multiplication by a constant).

Comment: The focus of portfolio optimization is the correlation among assets. If assets are perfectly related, the risk-parity approach does not do you any good. By the way, what exactly is the benefits of this risk-parity approach ? (purely for diversification ? )

Comment: The model you are trying to solve is a convex QP, which can be solved with solvers like cplex and [gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/) which are free for students and have c# interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I solved it using Nelder-Mead's algorithm instead. The performance could be better, but I didn't want to waste any more time in it.

Here's the final solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Extreme.Statistics;
using Extreme.Mathematics;
using Extreme.Mathematics.Optimization;

namespace TestingRiskParityOptimization
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<Vector, double> distance = DistanceFunction;


            NelderMeadOptimizer nm1 = new NelderMeadOptimizer();
            nm1.ObjectiveFunction = DistanceFunction;
            nm1.ContractionFactor = 0.5;
            nm1.ExpansionFactor = 2;
            nm1.ReflectionFactor = -2;
            nm1.SolutionTest.AbsoluteTolerance = 1e-15;
            nm1.InitialGuess = Vector.CreateConstant(2, 1.0 / ((double)2));
            nm1.ExtremumType = ExtremumType.Minimum;
            Vector solution = nm1.FindExtremum();

            Console.WriteLine("Solution: {0:F6}", solution);
            Console.WriteLine("  Estimated error: {0}", nm1.EstimatedError);
            Console.WriteLine("  # iterations: {0}", nm1.IterationsNeeded);
            Console.WriteLine("  # function evaluations: {0}", nm1.EvaluationsNeeded);
            Console.Write("Press Enter key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }


        private static double DistanceFunction(Vector Weights)
        {
            Matrix Sigma = Matrix.Create(new double[,] {
                  {0.1, 0.23},
                  {0.23, 0.7}
                });
            // if VarP = Weights' * CovarMatrix * Weights and VolP = sqrt(VarP)
            // Then the marginal contribution to risk of an asset is the i-th number of
            // Sigma*Weights*VolP
            // And thus the contribution to risk of an asset is simply Weights . (Sigma*Weights/VarP)
            // we need to find weights such that Weights (i) * Row(i) of (Sigma*Weights/VarP) = 1/N

            // that is we want to minimize the distance of row vector (Weights (i) * Row(i) of (Sigma*Weights/VarP)) and vector 1/N

            double Variance = Vector.DotProduct(Weights, Sigma * Weights);

            Vector Beta = Sigma * Weights / Variance;

            for (int i = 0; i < Beta.Length; i++)
            {
                // multiplies row of beta by weight to find the percent contribution to risk
                Beta[i] = Weights[i] * Beta[i];
            }

            Vector ObjectiveVector = Vector.CreateConstant(Weights.Length, 1.0 / ((double)Weights.Length));
            Vector Distance = Vector.Subtract(Beta, ObjectiveVector);

            return Math.Sqrt(Vector.DotProduct(Distance, Distance));

        }
    }
}
```